# Javascript getElementById lookups - hash map or recursive tree traversal?

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid

Does the DOM have a hash-table of elements whose keys are the elements' ids?
I want to know if `document.getElementById` looks up a hash table or traverses the entire tree.
Is this behavior different across browsers?

Comment: I'm not quite sure it's a good question. A good question might be "What is the best way of finding an element with a given ID", and `getElementById` is likely the best answer. How is it implemented?  That's peeping into a black box. There are probably too many browsers for a definitive answer.

Comment: @sash: You might also be interested in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406097/how-do-the-various-javascript-optimization-projects-affect-dom-performance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Implementations are free to do whatever they like, but since `id` is defined as a unique value, it would seem sensible to use a hash map or similiar lookup mechanism rather than traversal. What seems sensible from the outside, though, may not be when you get into the plumbing of building a complex web browser with many (sometimes conflicting) imperatives.

I did an easy **but very simplistic** test (see page at end of answer). It's **very** simplistic not least because we don't know that browsers don't cache previous results.

**Chrome 4.1.249.1059** reports:

```
ID: 0.0082ms per lookup
Tag: 0.0249ms per lookup
```

So, dramatically faster by ID than tag name.

**IE7** reports:

```
ID: 2.4438ms per lookup
Tag: 0.0437ms per lookup
```

So dramatically faster by tag name than ID (but remember IE7 has a [broken concept of `getElementById`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/by-any-other-name-would-smell-as-sweet.html); this is fixed in IE8).

**IE8** (on a *different machine*, don't compare absolutes, we're looking at diffs within the browser tested) reports:

```
ID: 1.1335ms per lookup
Tag: 0.0287ms per lookup
```

So about the same as IE7.

**Firefox 3.6.3** reports:

```
ID: 0.0042ms per lookup
Tag: 0.006ms per lookup
```

So it doesn't care that much (on repeated requests; **again**, it may be caching).

**Opera 10.5.1** reports:

```
ID: 0.006ms per lookup
Tag: 1.467ms per lookup
```

Dramatically faster by ID than tag name.

Make of those results what you will. A more complex test case would be needed to really infer the mechanisms. Of course, in at least two of those cases (Firefox and Chrome), **we can go look at the source**. CMS kindly [points us](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711303/javascript-getelementbyid-lookups-hash-map-or-recursive-tree-traversal/2711517#2711517) to the [WebKit](http://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit/trunk/WebCore/dom/Document.cpp) and [Firefox](http://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-1.9.2/file/5af70883c1de/content/base/src/nsDocument.cpp#l3932) implementations (and looking at it, my suspicion about caching may have been [on the money](http://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-1.9.2/file/5af70883c1de/content/base/src/nsDocument.cpp#l3900)).

Test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test Page</title>
<style type='text/css'>
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#log p {
    margin:     0;
    padding:    0;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = pageInit;
function pageInit() {
    document.getElementById('btnGo').onclick = btnGoClick;
}
function btnGoClick() {

    log("Testing...");
    setTimeout(run, 0);
}

function run() {
    var count, time;

    try {
        // Warm up
        testid(10);
        testtag(10);

        // Test
        count = 10000
        time = testid(count);
        log("ID: " + (time / count) + "ms per lookup");
        time = testtag(count);
        log("Tag: " + (time / count) + "ms per lookup");
    }
    catch (e) {
        log("Error: " + (e.message ? e.message : String(e)));
    }
}

function testid(count) {
    var start;

    start = new Date().getTime();
    while (count-- > 0) {
        if (!document.getElementById('fred')) {
            throw "ID 'fred' not found";
        }
    }
    return new Date().getTime() - start;
}

function testtag(count) {
    var start;

    start = new Date().getTime();

    while (count-- > 0) {
        if (document.getElementsByTagName('em').length == 0) {
            throw "Tag 'em' not found";
        }
    }
    return new Date().getTime() - start;
}

function log(msg) {
    var log = document.getElementById('log');
    log.innerHTML += "<p>" + msg + "<\/p>";
}
</script>
</head>
<body><div>
<input type='button' id='btnGo' value='Go'>
<div id='log'></div>
<hr>
<div>test test<span>test<span>test<span>test<span>test</span></span></span></span></div>
<div>test test<span>test<span>test<span>test<span>test</span></span></span></span></div>
<div>test test<span>test<span>test<span>test<span>test</span></span></span></span></div>
<div>test test<span>test<span>test<span>test<span>test</span></span></span></span></div>
<!-- repeat the above a couple of thousand times; I had about 2,200 -->
<div>test test<span>test<span>test<span>test<span>test</span></span></span></span></div>
<div>test test<span>test<span>test<span>test<em id='fred'>test</em></span></span></span></div>
</div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ROMANARMY: That needs a *lot* more content (see the inline comment in the HTML).

Comment: @T.J. - Nice test, I tried to add the content on jsbin, but seems that they have a size limit, I've uploaded it [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35146/js/tests/getElementById.html).

Comment: According to the question, you'll do better comparing `getElementById('log')` and `getElementById('fred')` - one is close to the beginning, and the other is after many elements (optimally, it'd been deeper too). If the search is linear you might see a difference. You are assuming `getElementsByTagName` is linear, but is also building a large collection.

Comment: @Kobi: A very good point. Can't do that right now, but may do it in a few hours.

Comment: I was tempted to mark @CMS's answer but i have to give it to Crowder. The answer i infer is - it depends. At least the first lookup doesn't seem to come from a hastable atleast for IE. Interesting how getElementsByTag is faster than id. We'll have to relook at some of our scripts.

Answer (score 28):

I know about the Firefox and WebKit DOM implementations, both of them use a hashtable to lookup the elements, digging into the source of them you can give a look to the internal implementations:

WebKit implementation, [Document.cpp](http://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit/trunk/WebCore/dom/Document.cpp), uses the hashtable if the `id` is unique, otherwise it traverses the document to get the first match:

```
Element* Document::getElementById(const AtomicString& elementId) const
{
    if (elementId.isEmpty())
        return 0;

    m_elementsById.checkConsistency();

    Element* element = m_elementsById.get(elementId.impl());//<-- hastable lookup
    if (element)
        return element;

    if (m_duplicateIds.contains(elementId.impl())) {
        // We know there's at least one node with this id,
        // but we don't know what the first one is.
        for (Node *n = traverseNextNode(); n != 0; n = n->traverseNextNode()) {
            if (n->isElementNode()) {
                element = static_cast<Element*>(n);
                if (element->hasID() &&
                element->getAttribute(element->idAttributeName()) == elementId) {
                    m_duplicateIds.remove(elementId.impl());
                    m_elementsById.set(elementId.impl(), element);
                    return element;
                }
            }
        }
        ASSERT_NOT_REACHED();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Firefox implementation, [nsDocument.cpp](http://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-1.9.2/file/5af70883c1de/content/base/src/nsDocument.cpp#l3932)

Comment: +1 Interesting. So, using the same `id` twice not only makes your document invalid, it also makes performance worse.

Comment: @CMS the hashtable might just be used for caching. We'll only know if we run tests on a large DOM.

Answer (score 2):

The specific implementation isn't defined in the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) so it could easily vary browser to browser.  For example [IE documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536437%28VS.85%29.aspx) states

> Returns a reference to the first object with the specified value of the ID  or NAME  attribute.

so I'd be tempted to say it does a search (or it just throws out elements in cases of hash collisions).

**EDIT** Also keep in mind there are other data structures (like trees) that allow for access time somewhere between constant and linear.

Comment: Remember that IE's implementation -- the bit you quoted -- is broken, completely at odds with the behavior specified by the W3C. They fixed this in IE8, fortuntely.

Comment: Good point.  To be fair W3C says **...Behavior is not defined if more than one element has this ID.** Technically IE can't be wrong wrong if the correct behavior isn't defined.

Comment: @ROMANARMY: The wrong bit is intermixing `name` with `id`. If you have duplicate IDs in your documents, as you say, whatever the browser wants to do (including ignoring all of them) is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be hard to test.

If it's tree-based then making a *very* deep tree (via Javascript) should be a good test case.

Comment: Please please answer the question  and dont post to get rep.

Comment: Yes, please make that test, on at least 3 major browsers.

Comment: @Srinivas: have you seen my rep? I could care less.

Comment: Is there some unwritten rule that I shouldn't contribute to the discussion unless my life depends on gaining XP^H^Hrep points?

Comment: @David: what ever the reason,i and MOST of SO users post answers when they know answer.nothing personal please :)

Comment: This answer would be a good comment, but I guess it's posted as an answer because you state that you care more about reputation than you otherwise might.