# Running time of document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, optimization, dom, performance

What is the running time of `document.getElementById`? It is at most logarithmic `O(log(n))`, where n is the number of elements in the DOM, because the DOM is a tree. It could also be constant `O(1)`, if during parsing of the HTML document, all elements with IDs are stored in a hash. I keep on hearing browsers touting their brand spanking new javascript engine with improved DOM accesses, so I'm not even sure if the running time is the same across all browsers.

The reason I ask if because I read this on [Mozilla's WebGL tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebGL/Getting_started_with_WebGL):

> The first thing we do here is obtain a
>   reference to the canvas, stashing it
>   in a global variable called canvas.
>   Obviously if you don't need to
>   repeatedly reference the canvas, you
>   could avoid saving this value, and you
>   could also save it in a local variable
>   or member field of an object.

Maybe doing $('canvasId') is not really as cheap as a constant operation if Mozilla gave this warning. Maybe I should rewrite my code from:

```
$('id').writeAttribute('foo', 'bar');
console.info($('id').getWidth());
$('id').absolutize();
```

to:

```
var element = $('id');
element.writeAttribute('foo', 'bar');
console.info(element.getWidth());
element.absoltize();
```

Comment: I don't see the warning in the quote you provided. It just explain that you can either hold the variable or not. I would certainly use local variable within one function, but would avoid having a global variable. But definitely 2nd example is faster (the question is for how much though).

Comment: You might find this post relevant to your interests: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711303/javascript-getelementbyid-lookups-hash-map-or-recursive-tree-traversal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping a copy of a DOM node in a local variable is always better when you have to access that element multiple times. That said, I can't imagine you'll notice a difference with only three lines of code accessing that element.